# Why do blender crash?

Tags: edit-mode

Hello iam new to blender,
when I started to make a high poly mesh it is not responding(blender 3d crashes)
I have a 4 gb ram I3 processor 1 tb hard disk laptop is it a reason pls help how to fix it

Comment: 4GB of RAM does not seem adequate for anything high poly. It's quite likely your laptop is the problem depending on what you mean by high poly.

Comment: High poly means I used subdivison surface solidify and mirror at the same time in one object

Comment: How to fix it jentlemen

Comment: Buying a new more powerful computer with a lot more RAM and better GPU would probably fix it. Else than that, trying to work smart could also be some sort of solution - maybe don't use subdivision modelling - it's quite wasteful in terms of unnecessary geometry. You can also work on smaller parts of what you are doing at a time while hiding everything you are not working on.

Comment: maybe you should tell us what statistics say? number of vertices/faces? using a subdivision surface modifier doesn't make Blender crash...

Comment: This question feels equivalent to, “I tried to drive up a mountain with a heavy cargo and it didn’t work. I have a small sedan with a 4 cylinder engine and a large trailer. How to fix?” As others stated, by analogy, if you aren’t able to use a more powerful car, try to find a way around the mountain, or don’t haul as much cargo at once.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the

Hardware Requirements

**Minimum**

64-bit quad core CPU with SSE2 support

**8 GB RAM**

Full HD display
Mouse, trackpad or pen+tablet
Graphics card with 2 GB RAM, OpenGL 4.3
Less than 10 year old

https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/